# Como usar uma Array para sortear elementos?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

eu tenho esse código

```
 With SerialPort1
            .Write("AT" & vbCrLf)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            .Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            .Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & txtnumber.Text & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
            .Write(txtmessage.Text & Chr(26))
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        End With
```

digamos que no `txtmessage.Text` eu queira colocar tipo `mensagem[i].Text` com uma lista de Array.

**Exemplo:**

```
    Private Sub menssagem(txtmessage, TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5, TextBox6, TextBox7, TextBox8)
    Dim menssagem(8) As Integer

End Sub
```

no total são 9 `TextBox` que eu quero que sejam sorteadas para seguir com a função.

Outra coisa, no `SerialPort1` é possivel eu inserir uma lista de array também? E se o `SerialPort12`, digamos assim, ela esteja sem resposta, tem como dar um **Next** para o proximo da lista de array?

Answer (score 2):

Se eu entendi, você só tem que usar [`Rnd()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2(v=vs.90).aspx):

```
    With SerialPort1
        .Write("AT" & vbCrLf)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        .Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        .Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & txtnumber.Text & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
        .Write(mensagem[CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 9))].Text & Chr(26))
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End With
```

Comment: valeu parça a atenção, acho que ja entendi o que tenho que fazer ! Obrigado

Comment: @MandrakeVenom Joia. [Veja aqui como o site funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Até a próxima!

Answer (score 2):

Olá fiz um exemplo em C#, você pode adaptá-lo para VB:

```
TextBox[] array = new TextBox[10];
array[0] = textBox1;
array[1] = textBox2;
array[2] = textBox3;
array[3] = textBox4;
array[4] = textBox5;
array[5] = textBox6;
array[6] = textBox7;
array[7] = textBox8;
array[8] = textBox9;
array[9] = textBox10;
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
     Thread.Sleep(200);
     var index = r.Next(array.Length);
     array[index].Text = $"Indice sortiado {index}, nome do textbox  {array[index].Name}";
}
```

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: eu posso fazer a mesma coisa com o `SerialPort1` ? tenho 12 [SerialPort]

Comment: Sim, o algorítimo é o mesmo.

Comment: só pra finalizar, se eu coloca esse codigo em vb.net dentro de uma Private Sub, depois é só eu escreve isso na função ? `.Write(array[index].Text & Chr(26))`

Comment: @MandrakeVenom sim você pode fazer exatamente isto